# Is the fight or flight response considered voluntarily or involuntarily?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience

I look in my rearview and see someone feet from me still speeding up and my heart rate feels like it doubles.  It stayed like that for an hour.  Had troubles concentrating and working well into the afternoon.  Is this normal to have trouble concentrating after a fight response?  Is the fight or flight response considered voluntarily or involuntarily?  What is a appropriate time to recover from a scare like this?

Comment: fight or flight or, maybe fight or not-fight but seeking shelter/protection etc.
babies have little knowledge and knowledge based voluntary responses, its more hormones like testosteron for boys.
If you get used to many , same of a kind responses, this response pattern becomes more and more part of you.
So voluntary or not?, I think your learned behavior is dominant.